# Performance issue using dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to make a simple dashboard using dc.js and bootstrap. The charts I'm showing are a simple series chart with three different series taken from a csv with approximately 9000 lines, a pie chart to select from those series and a bar chart to act as a date range selector.

It all works correctly but the performance is horrible. I assume it must be due to my lack of experience with crossfilter, as the example (http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/) uses 6000 records and performs really fast. Any ideas? I'm sorry for the lack of concreteness  but I'm a bit lost here.

My code is here:

```
d3.csv(sourceFile, function(error, data) {  
        data = data.splice(min,max);
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.Date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.Year=d.Date.getFullYear();
            d.Day = d3.time.day(d.Date);
        });
        var ndx2 = crossfilter(melt(data,["Date","Year","Day","date"],"Resource"));
        var meltedDim  = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return d.Resource;});
        var dateDim = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return d.Date;});
        var dateTypeDim = ndx2.dimension (function(d) {return [d.Date,d.Resource];});
        var valueGroup = dateTypeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.value});
        var dayDim = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return d.Day;});
        var volumeByDayGroup = dayDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
            return d.value/50;
        });
        var yearDim  = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;}); 
        var year_total = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.value;});
        var resourceDim  = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return d.Resource;});
        var value_resource = resourceDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return 1;}); 

        var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].Date;
        var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].Date;

        var xAxisWidth = 1000;

        var dateRangePicker = dc.barChart("#rangeTable");
        dateRangePicker
            .width(xAxisWidth).height(80)
            .margins({top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 65})
            .dimension(dayDim)
            .group(volumeByDayGroup)
            .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
            .gap(1)
            .round(d3.time.day.round)
            .elasticY(true)
            .xUnits(d3.time.days)
            .yAxis().ticks(4);

            var chart = dc.seriesChart(htmlID);
          chart
            .width(xAxisWidth).height(600)
           .dimension(dateDim)
           .group(valueGroup)
           .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[1]})
           .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0]})
           .valueAccessor(function (d) {return d.value})               
           .elasticY(false)
          .ordinalColors(["#56B2EA","#E064CD","#F8B700"])
           .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
           .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]))
           .elasticX(true)
           .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 00, left: 10})
           .brushOn(false)
           .transitionDuration(1000)
           .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
           .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
           .rangeChart(dateRangePicker)
           .mouseZoomable(false)
           .legend(dc.legend().x(xAxisWidth-65).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
                   .margins({ top: 10, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 50 }) 
           .yAxisLabel("Resource Percentage");




        var resourceRingChart = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-resource");
        resourceRingChart
            .width(170).height(170)
            .ordinalColors(["#56B2EA","#E064CD","#F8B700"])
            .dimension(resourceDim)
            .group(value_resource)
            .legend(dc.legend().x(75).y(63).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
            .renderLabel(false)
            .renderTitle(false)
            .innerRadius(50); 



        //dc.renderAll();
        dateRangePicker.render();
        chart.render();
        resourceRingChart.render();



        function getvalues(d){
            var str=d.key.getDate() + "/" + (d.key.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.key.getFullYear()+"\n";
            var key_filter = dateDim.filter(d.key).top(Infinity);
            var total=0;
            key_filter.forEach(function(a) {
            str+=a.Resource+": "+a.value+"%\n";
            total+=a.value;
            });
            dateDim.filterAll();
            return str;
        } 

        $("#resetButton").on("click",function(){
           chart.filterAll();
           chart.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]));
           chart.render();
           dateRangePicker.filterAll();
           resourceRingChart.filterAll();
           dc.redrawAll();
           $("#rangeSlider").slider("destroy");
            $("#rangeSlider").slider({
             range: true,
             min: 0,
             max: 100,
             values: [0,100],
           });
        });

         $("#axisButton").on("click",function(){
            var min = $('#rangeSlider').slider("option", "values")[0];
            var max = $('#rangeSlider').slider("option", "values")[1];
            chart.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([min,max]));
            chart.render();
        });

        $("#rangeSlider").slider({
              range: true,
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              values: [0,100],
            });
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found the reason, when crossfiltering: `var dateTypeDim = ndx2.dimension (function(d) {return [d.Date,d.Resource];});` increases the execution time in a 100 factor. There seems to be a performance issue when crossfiltering through more than one dimension.

Comment: I don't think that should be the problem generally with Crossfilter (I use dimensions of arrays in much larger data sets with no problems). It might be something the dc.js is doing inefficiently though, maybe with the accessor functions. I'd recommend you use a profiler to see where exactly the slowdown is happening.

Comment: I used some Javascript code to tell me the time it took to complete each task in the code above. As an example, these are the results with 5000 lines of the csv:

`Time taken for forEach: 29 ms.
Time taken for crossfiltering: 14828 ms.
Time taken for graph defining: 10 ms.
Time taken for rendering: 3186 ms.`

Comment: Apart from that, using a CPU profiler, I can see this: `Self:66.60%
TOTAL: 67.49% RegExp: //@[ ]sourceMappingURL=[ ]*([^\s'"]*)[ ]*$`, so it seems querying in a same dimension with strings and numbers isn't something nice for crossfilter.

Comment: Changing the date to a number using Date.getTime() and factorizing the resource type to an integer solved the problem: from 30 seconds down to 700 ms for 9000 lines.

Comment: So your dateTypeDim dimension still has structure [a, b], but 'a' and 'b' are now numbers? Makes sense. In our situation we are using dimensions with similar structure (numbers, strings) and not seeing performance issues. Good to know how much of an impact complex objects have - I knew they were slow, but not the magnitude of the slowness. Thanks for investigating.

Answer (score 1):

When using dimensions, it's best to avoid strings,dates and complex objects. Turn everything you can into integers, as it sorts the contents of the data based on your variables.